# Where is cell fracture in blender 2.8?

Tags: add-on, blend-files

Where is cell fracture add on in blender 2.8 ?
it is no longer available or have another name?

Comment: I don't think it will ever be in 2.8 (I may be wrong) it is getting something way better, Fracture Modifier. However it was supposed to be in the official release of 2.8 but i think it got pushed back to 2.8.1.

Comment: CG Cookie just said there are builds with the addon here: https://blender.community/c/graphicall/. Not sure where the relevant post is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Preferences > Addons. On my build the addon was present twice, which was indicated by an info bubble in this section (see pic below). There will be listed two paths, one of which you'll have to delete.

[image: Preferences > Add-ons; showing warning bubble]

Comment: Oh, and I would suggest you delete the entire directory, not just the `__init__.py` file, to not leave a mess.